# (probability) Does P(not A or not B) exist????

Tags: probability

If 20 customers are eating at an restaurant
14 peoples order pizza (P(A)), 10 peoples order salad (P(B)),
6 peoples order pizza and salad (P(A and B))

P(A) = 14/20 = 7/10

P(B) =10/20 = 1/2

P(A and B) = 6/20 = 3/10

P(A or B) = 14/20 + 10/20 - 6/20 = 18/20 = 9/10

P(neither A nor B)= 1-P(A or B) = 1/10

But I can't figure it out who neither order pizza nor salad!
Every one have order something at least one.

Does P(not A or not B) exist????

Comment: What does it mean for a probability to exist? Do you mean "is it non-zero"?

Comment: Yes !!
It is my miscalculation. I have confused that all of customer have order  so I mean 1-P(A or B) = 0 but It's my wrong result 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Arthur's answer.

Your statement which says,

> Every one have order something at least one.

is untrue. Since $14$ people ordered pizza, out of these set of people $6$ have ordered salad also. $4$ people have only salad (dietitians).

So remaining $2$ are having nothing. ($2/20$, in your expressions this is "P(neither A nor B)")

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I got it Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: "not A or not B" is equivalent to "not (A and B)", the same way you've already used that "not A and not B" ("neither A nor B") is equivalent to "not (A or B)" in your last line of calculations.

Comment: Oh thank you so much!!!